# for loop to iterate links to web scraping using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate some links into a loop for to scrape some web pages and fill a dataframe

This is my code:

```
from typing import Generator
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import islice
import mysql.connector
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

torneo = 0

for i in torneo:
   i + 1

match torneo:   
   
    case "0":
        matchlinkok = "https://www.betexplorer.com/football/chile/primera-division/results/"
        camp = "Chi-A"

    case "1":
        matchlinkok = "https://www.betexplorer.com/football/algeria/ligue-1/results/"
        camp = "Alg-A"

    case "2":
        matchlinkok = "https://www.betexplorer.com/football/australia/a-league/results/"
        camp = "Aus-A" 

    case "3":
        matchlinkok = "https://www.betexplorer.com/football/austria/bundesliga/results/"
        camp = "Aut-A"   

    case _:
        print("nothing???")
   

matchlink = matchlinkok

NM = 20

def _get_rows(url: str) -> Generator[dict[str, str], None, None]:
    session = HTMLSession()

    r = session.get(matchlink)

    allmatch = r.html.find(".in-match")
    results = r.html.find(".h-text-center a")
    matchodds = r.html.find("[data-odd]")

    odds = [matchodd.attrs["data-odd"] for matchodd in matchodds]

    idx = 0
    N = NM
    for match, res in islice(zip(allmatch, results), N):

        if res.text == "POSTP.":
            continue

        if res.text == "0:2 ABN.":
            continue

        if res.text == "0:3 AWA.":
            continue

        if res.text == "3:0 AWA.":
            continue

        if res.text == "0:2 CAN.":
            continue
        
        if res.text == "2:0 CAN.":
            continue

        if res.text == "1:1 CAN.":
            continue
       
 

        print(f"{match.text} Z {res.text} {', '.join(odds[idx:idx+3])}")
        yield {
            "match": match.text,
            "result": res.text,
            "odds": ", ".join(odds[idx : idx + 3]),
            "best_bets": (odds[idx]), "oddtwo": (odds[idx+1]), "oddthree": (odds[idx+2]),
        }

        idx += 3


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.DataFrame(_get_rows(matchlink))#.set_index("match") 
    df[['home','away']] = df['match'].str.split("-",expand=True)     
    df[['scorehome','scoreaway']] = df['result'].str.split(":",expand=True) 
    df = df.astype({'scorehome':'int'})
    df = df.astype({'scoreaway':'int'})
    cols = ['scorehome', 'scoreaway']
    #df['tournament'] = "Oma-A"
    df['tournament'] = camp
    df['sum_stats'] = df[cols].sum(axis=1, numeric_only=True)
    df['over05'] = np.where(df['sum_stats']>0, 'OK', 'NO')
    df['over15'] = np.where(df['sum_stats']>1, 'OK', 'NO')
    df['over25'] = np.where(df['sum_stats']>2, 'OK', 'NO')
    df['over35'] = np.where(df['sum_stats']>3, 'OK', 'NO')
    df['over45'] = np.where(df['sum_stats']>4, 'OK', 'NO')
    df['goal'] = np.where((df['scorehome'] >= 1) & 
         (df['scoreaway'] >= 1), 'OK', 'NO')
    df['esito'] = [ '1' if score_home > score_away else '2' if score_home < score_away else 'X' 
               for score_home, score_away in zip(df['scorehome'], df['scoreaway'])]
    
    df['result'] = df['result'].str.replace(':','-')
    colss = ['home', 'away', 'result']
    df['uniquefield'] = df[colss].apply(lambda row: ' '.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
    df = df[['home','away','scorehome','scoreaway','result','best_bets','oddtwo','oddthree', 'sum_stats', 'over05', 'over15', 'over25', 'over35', 'over45', 'goal', 'esito', 'tournament', 'uniquefield']]

    print(df)
```

At the moment I get this error:

> for i in torneo:
> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

I don't know if indent is correct, but I think so

My goal is to iterate integer number and pass it on match cases, get the link for each case in matchlinkok, and pass it to matchlink

Thanks for your time

Comment: *torneo* isn't iterable because it's an int. That's what the error message is telling you

Comment: @SIGHUP thanks, is there a solution to do what I'd like to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using some kind of counter, put the URL components into a list then you can just iterate over that.

In this code the implementation of _get_rows() is a dummy.

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

parts = [
    ("chile", "primera-division", "Chi-A"),
    ("algeria", "ligue-1", "Alg-A"),
    ("australia", "a-league", "Aus-A"),
    ("austria", "bundesliga", "Aut-A")
]

def _get_rows(url: str) -> Iterable:
    ...

for country, division, _ in parts:
    url = f"https://www.betexplorer.com/football/{country}/{division}/results"
    _get_rows(url)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have a question: inside mu def _get_rows, you can see my original code, I have the code to scrape elements from that web pages. But with your code you pass the link after. I don't understand how can implement it in my code, honestly. sorry for the question

Comment: Ok, it's working, but it iterate just the first one, and not all links. How can I do it? thanks

Comment: @Franky77 You must have mistyped something. This code will invoke _get_rows() 4 times